# django forms: setting a different initial form values on same page

Tags: django, django-forms

As you see in the html bellow, my code generates a table from data with a form in each row. When you submit the form, it posts data based on the row it was in. This works well. However, I need the initial data in the field to be different for each row. It has to be a calculated value based on the data the row is associated with. Is there maybe some django template code I can use to set this? Or is there maybe a way I can pass that value from the view?

```
{% for liquor in filter %}

<tr>
<td>{{ liquor.LiquorCode }}</td>
<td><a href="/liquors/get/{{ a.StoreID }}/{{ liquor.id }}/{{ SPI }}/">{{ liquor.BrandName }}</a></td>
<td>{{ liquor.VendorName }}</td>
<td>{{ liquor.LiquorType }}</td>
<td>{{ liquor.Proof }}</td>
<td>{{ liquor.BottleSize }}</td>
<td>{{ liquor.PackSize }}</td>
<td>{{ liquor.OffPremisePrice }}</td>
<td>{{ liquor.ShelfPrice }}</td>
<td>{{ liquor.GlobalTradeItemNumber1 }}</td>
<td><form action="/stores/quickadd/{{ a.StoreID }}/{{ liquor.id }}/{{ SPI }}/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

{{form.as_p}}


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Store"></td>
</tr>

    {% endfor %}
```

Here is my view:

```
def product_list(request, store_id):
    store = Store.objects.get(StoreID=store_id)
    f = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Liquor.objects.all())
    LiqSPI = StoreLiquor.objects.filter(storeID=store_id).count()
    AddLiqForm = AddLiquorForm()

    args = {}
    args['filter'] = f
    args['a'] = store
    args['SPI'] = LiqSPI + 1
    args['form'] = AddLiqForm
    return render(request,'UPC_filter.html', args)

def quickadd(request, store_id, liquor_id, SPI):
    storeID = Store.objects.get(StoreID=store_id)
    liquorID = Liquor.objects.get(id=liquor_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        AddLiqForm = AddLiquorForm(request.POST)
        if AddLiqForm.is_valid():
            StoreLiqID = AddLiqForm.save(commit=False)
            StoreLiqID.storeID = storeID
            StoreLiqID.liquorID = liquorID
            StoreLiqID.StorePrice = request.POST.get('StorePrice', '')
            StoreLiqID.SPI = SPI
            StoreLiqID.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/stores/UPC_Scan/%s' % store_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code i can see you are using django form of name AddLiquorForm.
If you want to fill initial data while form load you can aovveride **_*init*** method of your class you wrote for form(AddLiquorForm).

```
class AddLiquorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #code responsible to  create form fields 
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddLiquorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field1'].initial = 'whatever you want'                                        
        self.fields['field2'].initial = 'whatever you want'
        self.fields['field3'].initial = 'whatever you want'
        # other fields
```

Answer (score 0):

To display computed values based on stored values in your `Liquor` model, you can use model properties.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-methods

E.g.

```
class Liquor(models.Model):
""" Your fields up here.. liquor_code, liquor_type, proof """ 

    def _get_breed_proof(self):
        "Returns the liquor type + proof."
        return '%s %s' % (self.proof, self.liquor_type)
    breed_proof = property(_get_breed_proof)
```

You could then use in your template as any other model attribute -- `liquor.breed_proof`.